# Backing up Sharepoint Site

Tags: sharepoint-server

I've recently created a site on sharepoint 2013, and i'm having difficulty trying to back-up the entire website. As mentioned before the website is new and I will begin a bug-bash session later this week on it, however i am worried that one of these testers may do damage that i cannot restore, which with permissions issue i think this will be the case.

Is there a way to essentially take a snapshot of the site, or back it up as a whole and store it locally on my sharepoint server using a GUI? (2012 r2) and if so, how do i restore it at a later time.

Please feel free to mark this as a already answered question, however i could not find my answer even when going through similiar questions

Thank you !

Aswad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the PoSh cmdlet `Backup-SPSite` to create a full fidelity site collection backup.